# Prototype scoped Spring bean incorrectly created at context creation time after upgrade to 4.1.4.RELEASE

Tags: spring, junit

I have a prototype scoped bean defined in my test Configuration that needs to be created using the ApplicationContext (`applicationContext.getBean("my-failing-prototype-bean", myStringParam`) because it has a String parameter that needs to be passed.

When I was on Spring 4.0.4 this worked just fine when I ran my tests. The context is loaded when I ran a test class and the prototype scoped bean was not created until it was needed. Now, the process of loading the context attempts to create an instance of my bean which fails because there is no suitable bean that matches the String parameter I need to manually pass to the bean's factory method.

After stepping through the context creation process, it appears that in an attempt to autowire a different bean, Spring is calling `DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType()` which calls `AbstraceAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getNonSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck()` which then calls `AbstraceAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance()` because `AbstraceAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation()` returns null.

EDIT: After distilling my project down to an sample project that produces the issue, I found it only occurs when the bean declared in my test Spring config implements either `FactoryBean`, `BeanFactoryAware`, or `BeanClassLoaderAware`. It also definitely only occurs when there is another bean injected into the test Spring config.

Thank you for your help and please let me know if there are any more details you would like!

[**GitHub repository for a simple project that reproduces this issue**](https://github.com/reid-harrison/my-failing-bean)

**TestSpringConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class TestSpringConfig {

    @Inject
    @Named("my-other-bean")
    MyOtherBean myOtherBean;

    @Inject
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Bean(name = {"my-failing-prototype-bean"})
    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    @Profile("test")
    public JndiObjectFactoryBean myFailingPrototypeBean(final String jndiName) {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean jof = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        JndiTemplate testJndiTemplate = new JndiTemplate();

        jof.setResourceRef(true);
        jof.setJndiTemplate(testJndiTemplate);
        jof.setJndiName(jndiNameForQueue);

        return jof;
    }
```

**MyTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestSpringConfig.class, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void runTest() { ...
```

**Stacktrace**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'TestSpringConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.me.MyOtherBean com.me.TestSpringConfig.myOtherBean; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'my-failing-prototype-bean' defined in com.me.TestSpringConfig: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.lang.String]: : No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.me.MyOtherBean com.me.TestSpringConfig.myOtherBean; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'my-failing-prototype-bean' defined in com.me.TestSpringConfig: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.lang.String]: : No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'my-failing-prototype-bean' defined in com.me.TestSpringConfig: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.lang.String]: : No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:464)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getNonSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:896)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:791)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:436)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1112)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 57 more
```

Comment: If it worked with Spring 4.0.x but doesn't with 4.1.x, then it's possibly a regression bug. You should probably file an issue with Spring.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I have opened an issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12786

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, having a bean as prototype does not stop it from being eagerly initialized. Try adding a @Lazy annotation to your bean.

```
@Bean(name = {"my-failing-prototype-bean"})
    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    @Profile("test")
    @Lazy
    public JndiObjectFactoryBean myFailingPrototypeBean(final String jndiName) {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean jof = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        JndiTemplate testJndiTemplate = new JndiTemplate();

        jof.setResourceRef(true);
        jof.setJndiTemplate(testJndiTemplate);
        jof.setJndiName(jndiNameForQueue);

        return jof;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but the @Lazy annotation didn't fix the problem. If you'd like, please check out the GitHub repo in my original question for a simple reproduction of the issue.